# Installing Kali Linux wireless drivers on chipset realtek rtl8811au

Tags: kali-linux

I've been trying to install drivers for my new Amped wireless UA230A external Wi-Fi antenna, I've been crawling all over git hub but cannot find any, if someone could help me find some compatible drivers and tell me how to install them that would be much appreciated..